# Comment section for an infinite scrolling blog page

Tags: comments, infinite-scroll

I came across many infinite scrolling blog pages and could not able to find an appropriate example of a comments section in a blog page with infinite scroll.

Is keeping an infinite scroll is even a best practice for a blog page? if so does having a comments section for each article is practical? or doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Readers who want to quickly skim relevant, interesting and useful content only care about the blog article and pictures. So a comment section is not that important to include in part of the scroll, in fact sometimes I only see a preview, enough to fit on one page height, and to get to the rest of the content, you would click "read more" or something. Once you click part of the article, you would go a page that has the full article and comments.
Facebook has a smart algorithm so that your newsfeed shows top comments only if they're relevant.